# Cs50's problem set 4, Blur function not working

Tags: c, cs50

I have been stuck on the Blur function from the problem set 4 of Harvard University's " Introduction to Computer Science" from last 4 hrs and I still can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

1. I've made a copy of the original image and then iterating through all the the pixels one by one.
2. Then I'm taking the avg. of all the surrounding pixels and copying them to the duplicate of the original image.
3. And in the end, I'm copying the pixel values of duplicate image to the original image.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    int sumRed=0,sumGreen=0,sumBlue=0;

    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            if(i==0 && j==0)
            {
                for(int k=i;k<=i+1;k++)
                {
                    for(int l=j;j<=j+1;j++)
                    {
                        sumRed+=image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                        sumGreen+=image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue+=image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                    }
                }
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed=sumRed/4;
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen=sumGreen/4;
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue=sumBlue/4;
                
            }
            else if(i>0 && j==0)
            {
                for(int k=i-1;k<=i+1;k++)
                {
                    for(int l=j;j<=j+1;j++)
                    {
                        sumRed+=image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                        sumGreen+=image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue+=image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                    }
                }
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed=sumRed/6;
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen=sumGreen/6;
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue=sumBlue/6;
            }
            else if(i==0 && j>0)
            {
                for(int k=i;k<=i+1;k++)
                {
                    for(int l=j-1;j<=j+1;j++)
                    {
                        sumRed+=image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                        sumGreen+=image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue+=image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                    }
                }
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed=sumRed/6;
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen=sumGreen/6;
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue=sumBlue/6;
            }
            else if(i>0 && j>0)
            {
                for(int k=i-1;k<=i+1;k++)
                {
                    for(int l=j-1;j<=j+1;j++)
                    {
                        sumRed+=image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                        sumGreen+=image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue+=image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                    }
                }
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed=sumRed/9;
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen=sumGreen/9;
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue=sumBlue/9;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed=copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen=copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue=copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: What is RGBTRIPLE?  Have you seen the image after blurring?  Does it look good?

Comment: You could use `memcpy()` to copy the image.

Comment: You didn't take into account the edges where `i == height - 1` or `j == width - 1`

Comment: I would just do one loop, and handle the exceptions in there, instead of writing specific code in many loops

Comment: There's also a typo: you are never writing to `copy[i][j].rgbtBlue` after the initial copying

Comment: Oh! Yeah!!! Thanks for telling about that typo

Comment: It's still not working, even after correcting the typo. :-(

Comment: I think the logic in the nested loops is not right. Did you check how is your code passing cs50 tests? Can you post the results?